# WorkManager: Periodic work not working expectedly

Tags: android, android-service, android-workmanager, android-background

**Note:** I have already checked out multiple similar post and tried all possible general solutions, and also most of the respected posts were almost an year old or more. Now I'm re-raising issue w.r.t to observation and efforts.

**Expectation:** Firstly, I am looking out to create a periodic service/work that should be running even the application got closed or terminated/cleared for recent. The purpose of this will be to hit any database on interval ---> fetch and trigger a notification to user.

Here is my current code:

MainActivity -> onCreate ->

```
PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            NotificationWorker.class,
            1, 
            TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .setConstraints(
                    new Constraints.Builder()
                            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                            .build()
            )
            .build();

 WorkManager.getInstance(this)
            .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("simplified", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest);
```

NotificationWorker class ->

```
public class NotificationWorker extends Worker {
private static final String TAG = "DANTE:NotifyWorker";
private Context mContext;
public NotificationWorker(@NonNull Context context,
                          @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
    mContext = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    Log.d(TAG, "doWork: called");
    NotificationManagerCompat mNotificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(mContext);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                "My app",
                "My app",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("My description.");
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, "My app");

    mNotificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Work manager")
            .setContentText(String.valueOf(new Date().getTime()))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_notification)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW);
    mNotificationBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, true);
    Notification notification = mNotificationBuilder.build();
    mNotificationManager.notify(121, notification);
    return Result.retry();
}

@Override
public void onStopped() {
    super.onStopped();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStopped: called");
}
```

**Observations:**

**1.** As per my understanding *PeriodicWorkRequest* work in background and executes *doWork* in interval in my case 1+ hour. But what I have noticed is as soon as app closes and cleared from recent, I never receive a callback/execution to *doWork* again even after waiting for hours and a day too.

**2.** As soon as I open app again after 3+ hours, I observer log stack and found out 3-4 times *doWork* getting logged **"doWork: called"** which is quiet surprising because I was expecting these logs to be printed on respected intervals.

**3.** After app close and cleared for recent, my notification also removed from the notification bar, which I never expected as this is my primary use case for having *WorkManager*.

**4.** Just for understanding callbacks I have override *onStopped* also added log in so to get insight, but it never gets called.

**Efforts:** After going through earlier similar post I have tried the listed below:

**1.** Changing ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy - > KEEP, REPLACE

**2.** Changing Constraints and accordingly wait for response.

**3.** Created custom provider *MyWorkManagerInitializer*, placed in AndroidManifest as provider and then executed exact PeriodicWorkRequest from *onCreate* and found the exact same behavior afore mentioned. I have tested way from medium post https://medium.com/@programmerr47/custom-work-manager-initialization-efdd2afa6459

**4.** While working on *MyWorkMangerInitializer* approach I didn't get any exception related to "Work Manager is disable* except in android version 21(Lollipop) which is kind of strange coz its was working on other higher level versions, but in all the working versions my observation was same.

**Actively looking out for clarification and solution regarding all observation. Thanks in advance for ur time :)**

Comment: I have faced this issue is latest WorkManager library  "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.4.0"

Comment: Where are you testing? on a Real device or Emulator? If you are testing on a Real device, who's the manufacturer? Because some devices (ex: MIUI) kill the android background processes when the app is killed or removed from the recent stack.

Comment: All testing is on emulator... and regarding Chinese manufacturer i  know they have this behaviour.. but this observation are on stock android.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. As I see nothing wrong in your code. One thing you can try. 

Return `Result.retry()` only when you encounter some exception, other than this try returning `Result.success()` 

Like this: 

`try {
yourWork()
} catch(exception) {
return Result.retry()
}

return Result.success()`

Comment: Yeah I have also tried that before, and it didn't worked.. So after that I try forcing it by returning "retry" but it didn't worked too, and I end up posting it here. Frankly saying after this I'm not too happy with WorkManager simplicity, as it limits understanding and debugging. 

Comment: @RajSingh have you found any solution to this problem?